# Switching an image with switch statement

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating my first project.

What I am trying to do is be able to switch an image from my unordered list nav-bar using the switch statement. I can easily create a function dedicated to each items in the list but i am working on a long list which will result to an unnecessarily long code hence the Switch statement.

Every time I click on a list item it just doesn't change the default image into an image that it is suppose to change into.

Here is my code so far:

```js
function changeImage(inobj) {

  switch (inobj) {
    case 'L1':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L2':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L3':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image5.jpg', 'image6.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L4':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image7.jpg', 'image8.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L5':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image9.jpg', 'image10.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L6':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image11.jpg', 'image12.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L7':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image13.jpg', 'image14.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L8':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image15.jpg', 'image16.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L9':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image17.jpg', 'image18.jpg'];
      break;
    case 'L0':
      document.getElementById('image').src = ['image19.jpg', 'image20.jpg'];
      break;

  }

}
```

```html
<!-- FIRST GROUP-->
<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>TOP TIER CARRIERS </strong><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id='parentlist' class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id='list' value='L1' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST1</li>
  <li id='list' value='L2' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST2</li>
  <li id='list' value='L3' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST3</li>
  <li id='list' value='L4' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST4</li>
  <li id='list' value='L5' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- SECOND GROUP-->

<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>TOP TIER CARRIERS </strong><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id='parentlist' class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id='list' value='L6' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST1</li>
  <li id='list' value='L7' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST2</li>
  <li id='list' value='L8' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST3</li>
  <li id='list' value='L9' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST4</li>
  <li id='list' value='L0' onClick='changeImage()'>LIST5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<center><img src="defaultimage.jpg" id="image" /></center>
```

What did I do wrong?! your inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're assigning an array to what should be a string. Choose just one of the images, you can't place both in the same `img` tag.

Comment: Why are you setting an image src to an array?

Comment: Just as a side note: IDs should be unique. So `id='list'` is bad if used more then once. Use class instead. Oh, and in this case li don't really have `value` attributes.

Comment: You are not passing any parameter to `changeImage()`. So, inside the function `inobj` is `undefined` and default case is executed every time.

Comment: You likely wanted something like `function changeImage(listNumber) { document.getElementById("image").src="image"+listNumber+".jpg"; }` and pass the list number in the onclick="changeImage(6)" or use unobtrusive coding and add an event listener to the ULs and grab a data-attribute from the LI clicked

Comment: hey guys. i appreciate your response. can you show your code for this instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple problems with the code, but the general approach is fine (for beginners)

You can only use `id`s once; they are unique identifiers, if you want to handle multiple elements as a group, use `class` instead

The `img` source is a string, you were trying to assign an array of strings

You failed to pass the reference of the clicked element to the function, that is why I've added the `this` to `changeImage()`; that will hold the clicked element

`li`s can not have `value` attributes, that is reserved for input types only (as far as I know), so I've replaced it to `data-value`

the `data-xxx` is a flexible attribute that you can use on (i think) any element, and you can substitute simple strings to the `xxx` part

```js
function changeImage(inobj) {

  switch (inobj.getAttribute('data-value')) {
    case 'L1':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L1';
      break;
    case 'L2':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L2';
      break;
    case 'L3':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L3';
      break;
    case 'L4':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L4';
      break;
    case 'L5':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L5';
      break;
    case 'L6':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L6';
      break;
    case 'L7':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L7';
      break;
    case 'L8':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L8';
      break;
    case 'L9':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L9';
      break;
    case 'L0':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=L0';
      break;

  }

}
```

```html
<!-- FIRST GROUP-->
<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>TOP TIER CARRIERS </strong><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id='parentlist' class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class='list' data-value='L1' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST1</li>
  <li class='list' data-value='L2' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST2</li>
  <li class='list' data-value='L3' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST3</li>
  <li class='list' data-value='L4' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST4</li>
  <li class='list' data-value='L5' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- SECOND GROUP-->

<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>TOP TIER CARRIERS </strong><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id='parentlist' class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class='list' data-value='L6' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST1</li>
  <li class='list' data-value='L7' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST2</li>
  <li class='list' data-value='L8' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST3</li>
  <li class='list' data-value='L9' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST4</li>
  <li class='list' data-value='L0' onClick='changeImage(this)'>LIST5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<center><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100?text=default" id="image" /></center>
```

Comment: Thank you Zed!!!! You guys are amazing!!! and thank you for the comments too. it is very helpful.

Comment: @cris you should accept one of the answers for future generations ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unobtrusive plain JS way of doing what you seem to want

I have fixed your duplicate IDs

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) { // whe page loaded
  document.querySelectorAll("li.list").forEach(function(li) { // all LIs
    li.onclick=function() { // each LI
      var image = "image"+this.getAttribute("data-image")+".jpg";
      console.log(image); // can be removed, only for demonstration
      document.getElementById("image").src = image;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- FIRST GROUP-->
<div>
<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>TOP TIER CARRIERS </strong><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu parentlist">
  <li class='list' data-image='1'>LIST1</li>
  <li class='list' data-image='2'>LIST2</li>
  <li class='list' data-image='3'>LIST3</li>
  <li class='list' data-image='4'>LIST4</li>
  <li class='list' data-image='5'>LIST5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- SECOND GROUP-->
<div>
<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>TOP TIER CARRIERS </strong><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu parentlist">
  <li class='list' data-image='6'>LIST1</li>
  <li class='list' data-image='7'>LIST2</li>
  <li class='list' data-image='8'>LIST3</li>
  <li class='list' data-image='9'>LIST4</li>
  <li class='list' data-image='10'>LIST5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<center><img src="defaultimage.jpg" id="image" /></center>
```

You can use  `this.getAttribute("data-image").replace("L","")` if you want to keep the "L1" format

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code
Used only two images in snippet

```js
 function changeImage(inobj) {
            
  
  switch (inobj) {
    case 'L1':
          document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg?5153';
      break;
    case 'L2':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg';
      break;
    case 'L3':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg?5153';
    case 'L4':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg';
      break;
    case 'L5':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg?5153';
      break;
    case 'L6':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg';
      break;
    case 'L7':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg?5153';
      break;
    case 'L8':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg';
      break;
    case 'L9':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg?5153';
      break;
    case 'L0':
      document.getElementById('image').src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg';
      break;

  }

}
```

```html
<div>
<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>TOP TIER CARRIERS </strong><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id='parentlist' class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id='list' value='L1' onClick='changeImage("L1")'>LIST1</li>
  <li id='list' value='L2' onClick='changeImage("L2")'>LIST2</li>
  <li id='list' value='L3' onClick='changeImage("L3")'>LIST3</li>
  <li id='list' value='L4' onClick='changeImage("L4")'>LIST4</li>
  <li id='list' value='L5' onClick='changeImage("L5")'>LIST5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- SECOND GROUP-->

<button name="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>TOP TIER CARRIERS </strong><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id='parentlist' class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id='list' value='L6' onClick='changeImage("L6")'>LIST1</li>
  <li id='list' value='L7' onClick='changeImage("L7")'>LIST2</li>
  <li id='list' value='L8' onClick='changeImage("L8")'>LIST3</li>
  <li id='list' value='L9' onClick='changeImage("L9")'>LIST4</li>
  <li id='list' value='L0' onClick='changeImage("L0")'>LIST5</li>
</ul>
</div>

<center><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg" id="image" /></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is mostly wrong on your code is that you are assigning an array where it should be a string, you can fix it with:

```
document.getElementById('image').src = 'image2.jpg';
```

Also, Id's are suposed to be unique.

If you want the image to be switched between the two options everytime the user clicks on it, than you can do something like this:

```
function changeImage(inobj) {
    switch (inobj) {
        case 'L1':
            document.getElementById('image').src = document.getElementById('image').src == 'image1.jpg' ? 'image2.jpg' : 'image1.jpg';
            break;
```

If you assign a unique ID to every li you can make things more interesting, and have the function receive the id, so you don't need the switch. Supose the id's are L1, L2, ...:

```
function changeImage(imageId) {
    imageNumber = imageId.substr(1);
    nextImageNumber = n % 2 == 0 ? imageNumber - 1 : imageNumber + 1
    document.getElementById('imageId').src = 'image' + nextImageNumber + '.jpg';
}
```

Comment: LOL. i am laughing at myself right now. I am getting a flak on how i am using my "id". I actually used the id for CSS. I am really thankful for this guys. I still have so much to learn.

Comment: Allways happy to help :) @cris